# Must provide source or customer using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

i am newbie in this site, i have error conserne payment by `laravel` uses `stripe`, i configured my `cartalyst/stripe-laravel` package, but it gives me error `must provide source or customer.` and I don't know where is error, and error mean what.

**CheckoutController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        try {
            $charge = Stripe::charges()->create([
                'amount' => Cart::total() / 100,
                'currency' => 'CAD',
                'source' => $request->stripeToken,
                'description' => 'Order',
                'receipt_email' => $request->email,
                'metadata' => [
                    //'contents' => $contents,
                    //'quantity' => Cart::instance('default')->count(),
                ],
            ]);

        return back()->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }
```

**checkout.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('checkout.store') }}"  method="post" id="payment-form">
                                    @csrf                    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="card-header">
                                            <label for="card-element">
                                                Enter your credit card information
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div id="card-element">
                                            <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                                            <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                    <button
                                    id="card-button"
                                    class="btn btn-dark"
                                    type="submit"
                                    data-secret="{{ $intent }}"
                                    > Pay </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script>
        // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
        // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)

        var style = {
            base: {
                color: '#32325d',
                lineHeight: '18px',
                fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
                fontSize: '16px',
                '::placeholder': {
                    color: '#aab7c4'
                },
            },
            invalid: {
                color: '#fa755a',
                iconColor: '#fa755a'
            }
        };
    
        const stripe = Stripe('{{ $stripe_key }}', { locale: 'en' }); // Create a Stripe client.
        const elements = stripe.elements(); // Create an instance of Elements.
        const cardElement = elements.create('card', { style: style }); // Create an instance of the card Element.
        const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
        const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
    
        cardElement.mount('#card-element'); // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    
        // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
        cardElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            if (event.error) {
                displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
            } else {
                displayError.textContent = '';
            }
        });
    
        // Handle form submission.
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        document.getElementById('complete-order').disabled = true;

        
    
        stripe.handleCardPayment(clientSecret, cardElement, {
                payment_method_data: {
                    //billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                }
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                if (result.error) {
                    // Inform the user if there was an error.
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                } else {
                    console.log(result);
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**.env**

```
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_p7FbGbClL...............
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_PcR.............
```

**services.php**

```
'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],
```

Comment: Tokens and Charges are deprecated and you should use PaymentMethods and PaymentIntents instead. Building an integration with the new PaymentIntents APIs allows your integration to handle dynamic payments, support authentication scenarios (such as 3D Secure), and help meet evolving payment regulations around the world (such as Strong Customer Authentication). You can learn more about implementing PaymentIntents here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents or implementing Stripe Checkout which uses PaymentIntents: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout.

Answer (score 0):

This error is returned by Stripe when you're trying to create a charging request without a customer or source identifier but According to your code, you have tried to access variable called `$request->stripeToken` but it is also not defined.

This is what you can do:

- ### Option #1

  Define the stripe token in your env and set it in the charging request

  .env

  ```
  STRIPE_TOKEN=XXXXXXXX
  ```

  controller

  ```php
  public function store(Request $request)
      {
          //dd($request->all());
          try {
              $charge = Stripe::charges()->create([
                  'amount' => Cart::total() / 100,
                  'currency' => 'CAD',
                  'source' => env("STRIPE_TOKEN", "somedefaultvalue"),
                  'description' => 'Order',
                  'receipt_email' => $request->email,
                  'metadata' => [
                      //'contents' => $contents,
                      //'quantity' => Cart::instance('default')->count(),
                  ],
              ]);

          return back()->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
          } catch (Exception $e) {

          }
      }
  ```
- ### Option #2

  Define the customer instead of the source. To do this, you first need to create a customer instead stripe and then pass the customer ID to the charging request:
  You can create a customer by the customer create method in the library that you use (https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0#create-a-customer)

  Then it will return a customer array. Use the `"id"` key in that as the customer identifier in your controller method:

  ```php
  public function store(Request $request)
      {
          //dd($request->all());
          try {
              $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
                  'email' => 'john@doe.com',
              ]);
              $charge = Stripe::charges()->create([
                  'amount' => Cart::total() / 100,
                  'currency' => 'CAD',
                  'customer' => $customer['id'],
                  'description' => 'Order',
                  'receipt_email' => $request->email,
                  'metadata' => [
                      //'contents' => $contents,
                      //'quantity' => Cart::instance('default')->count(),
                  ],
              ]);

          return back()->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
          } catch (Exception $e) {

          }
      }
  ```